# The statement of a theorem appearing on a new line

Tags: line-breaking, theorems, amsthm

I'm using the `amsthm` package. The statement of the theorem currently appears immediately after the words "Theorem X." I'd like the statement of the theorem to appear on a new line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Considering the following MWE

```
 1: \documentclass{article}
 2: 
 3: \usepackage{amsthm}
 4: \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
 5: 
 6: \begin{document}
 7: 
 8: \begin{thm}[Pythagoras' Theorem]
 9:   In a right angled triangle the square of the hypotenuse is
10:   equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides.
11: \end{thm}
12: 
13: \end{document}
```

there are two possible approaches.

1. **The *ad hoc* solution:**

   Simply adding a `~\\` at the end of line 8 of the MWE will yield your desired behaviour. However, you will have to do this every time you state a theorem.
2. **The 'correct' solution**

   Better yet, define your own theorem style using the `\newtheoremstyle` macro as shown in the [`amsthm` documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf). To do this, just insert the following lines between lines 3 and 4 of the MWE, i.e. directly before you define your `thm` environment:

   ```
   \newtheoremstyle{custom}%    <name>
                   {\topsep}%   <space above>
                   {\topsep}%   <space below>
                   {\itshape}%  <body font>
                   {}%          <indent amount>
                   {\bfseries}% <Theorem head font>
                   {.}%         <punctuation after theorem head>
                   {\newline}%  <space after theorem head> (default .5em)
                   {}%          <Theorem head spec>
   \theoremstyle{custom}
   ```

   The newline is produced by setting the 8th argument (space after theorem head) to `\newline`. The other parameters are the default settings of the `plain` style of `amsthm`. Of course, you can customize those as well, if you want your theorems to look different.