# Line break in \newtheoremstyle with itemize

Tags: theorems, itemize, amsthm

I am using `\newtheoremstyle` to define a theorem style that has a line break after the header. Following the template [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100143/63847), I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{custom}%    <name>
                {\topsep}%   <space above>
                {\topsep}%   <space below>
                {\itshape}%  <body font>
                {}%          <indent amount>
                {\bfseries}% <Theorem head font>
                {.}%         <punctuation after theorem head>
                {\newline}%  <space after theorem head> (default .5em)
                {}%          <Theorem head spec>
\theoremstyle{custom}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{thm}[Knuth's Theorem] 
    \TeX is great.
    \end{thm}

\end{document}
```

That works fine:

[image]

But if I replace the content of the theorem with

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \TeX is great.
\end{itemize}
```

then the line break disappears.

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: `\begin{thm}[Knuth's theorem]\mbox{}\begin{itemize}`

Comment: OK, but is there any way to incorporate this logic into the `\newtheoremstyle` itself so I don't have to do it manually every time?

Comment: I'm afraid not. This is a consequence of how lists are implemented.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Comment: In the `amsthm` user documentation, section 4.3.1 deals with exactly this question, defining `\theoremstyle{break}`.  `texdoc amsthdoc`

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. So the approach in the `amsthm` docs just uses `\newline` in the theorem definition (as above) but has a slightly nicer hack inside the theorem itself (`\leavevmode \vspace{-\baselineskip}`).